# Execute FQL Queries From .Net Facebook Developer Toolkit

Tags: facebook

Using the .Net Facebook Developer Toolkit, how do I execute FQL queries?

Answer (score 1):

Example of the FQL query with Facebook Developer Toolkit:

```
api.Fql.Query("SELECT contact_email FROM user WHERE uid=" + UserID);
```

as you can see FQL is pretty similar to the SQL. "Query" method returns XML.

[More documentation.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a object of Facebook.Rest.Api and then you can access fqlquery where you want to pass the query as string and you will get result in string.